# How to search hyphenated words

Tags: livecode

How to search hyphenated words eg(Alexander-great) if this word present in search list then the output should be like Alexander-great:1 here 1 indicate that how many time the particular word present in main Scrolling field I am using the following code.

```
on mouseUp
  put fld"MytextField"into Mytext   
put fld "SRText" into myData
   split myData by cr and colon
   put the keys of myData into myData

   repeat for each words myWord in Mytext
      if myWord is among the words of myData then
                  if myCounts[myWord] is empty then
            put 1 into myCounts[myWord]
            --answer "Haii"
         else
            add 1 to myCounts[myWord]

         end if
      end if
   end repeat
   combine myCounts by cr and colon
   put myCounts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code

```
if myWord contains the words of myData then
```

instead of

```
if myWord is among the words of myData then
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine as is, though you might check out a slightly more compact version:

```
   ...
repeat for each words myWord in Mytext
       if myWord is among the words of myData then add 1 to myCounts[myWord]
end repeat
...
```

Local variables in LC, including array variables, may be created and loaded on the fly. It is not necessary to either declare them or to create them with a default value. Please step through the handler, and watch the contents of the variable watcher.

Note that your method is not forbidden, but is unnecessarily verbose. You will become more efficient as you become more experienced.

Craig Newman

Comment: It's not working. It's same like my old output i want the output like        eg(ss:1,ss-dd:1,ss-ff:1) now i got the out ss:3 it's count ss-dd,ss-ff to ss it's does not treat ss-dd,ss-ff as separate word